# how to pass property value to PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean in applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-profiles

i want to pass environment name dynamically to  PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean, it is not reading from properties file & **default-application.properties** is in classpath

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
            <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:/${environmentName}/*.properties</value>
                </list>
            </property> 
      </bean>

    default-application.properties
    # Application Common Properties
    profile.name=dev
```

Comment: `<value>classpath*:default-application.properties</value>`, can you do this?

Comment: Yes,It is not working